# Terminate Jest as soon as first test fails

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Is there a straightforward way in Jest (v24.9.0) to trigger a teardown, return testing results, and terminate the Node process in which the tests are running as soon as Jest encounters the first test failure?

`--bail` exists but [this only terminates the test suite containing the failed test](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#bail) meaning that, even with `--bail`, any tests in subsequent suites will be executed.

If there's not a feature built into Jest to do this, I'd like to write some code to catch a test failure. In order to do this I'll need to figure out the mechanism by which Jest "detects" and "records" (sorry if these aren't the correct terms) test failures. If I can write a simple function to catch a failure, then I can terminate the Node process within this function. Does anyone know how I could programmatically "catch" a Jest test failure?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2867 <- this might be helpful.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40084732/104380

Comment: Also helpful: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2626